# Replace string and store on condition

Tags: python

I have a python script in which I defined a working directory `Directory_1` as a hardcoded string. If it's not present in the machine, it prompts to select some other directory `Directory_2`. `Directory_2` should replace directory.

Requirement: If the directory doesn't exist replace the hardcoded and have it in memory till the selected directory exists in the machine, for next runs. What should I do to store the user selection directory for multiple run of the same script.

```
#Python 

directory_1=r'C:/Users/XX/Weekly_report_generator/DTR_Py_REC'
exist=os.path.isdir(directory_1)

if not exist:
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from tkinter import *
    window=Tk()
    directory_2 = filedialog.askdirectory()
    directory_1=directory_2
    mainloop()
print(directory_1)
```

Comment: why not try saving the selected directory of the user to a configuration or text file; another one is to use environment variable I guess.

Comment: Yeah, a file in the user's home directory is the standard way to do this.  Using an environment variable won't work.  Your program will be running in a shell, and any edit to your environment will only affect that shell.  When your program execution ends, that shell goes away, and so does any change you made to the environment. - Since you're on Windows, you could potentially save this in the Windows Registry as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of saving a path in a file so the user doesn't have to specify it every time she runs the program:

```
from os.path import expanduser

def main():

    # The path to try first if the user hasn't specified a directory
    path = '/my/default/path'

    # Compute the path where we save the user's directory choice
    savedDirFile = expanduser("~/.report_gen_saved_dir")

    if os.path.exists(savedDirFile):
        # If we've saved a path away that the user specified in another run, load that path from file
        with open(savedDirFile) as f:
            path = f.read()
    elif not os.path.isdir(path):
        # Otherwise, if the default path isn't a valid directory, prompt the user for a directory
        # @@@ user interaction code here @@@
        path = '/some/user/selected/path' # Do your thing here to have the user specify a directory

        # Save off the user's directory choice for future runs
        with open(savedDirFile, "w") as f:
            f.write(path)

    print(path)

main()
```

This saves the selected directory in a file named **.report_gen_saved_dir** in the user's home directory.